# How to force the migration to use connection string of the client context triggered the migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

The application uses EF 6.1.2 to connect to the database. The database is automatically upgraded by the application using the EF migration feature.

However, the migration does call parameter-less constructor instead of using the connection string used by the client context which is triggering the migration. How to force the migration (which is triggered on the `var z = await y.ToListAsync();` line) to use the connection string supplied to the `clientContext`?

The connection string of the client context is supplied by the user (i.e. it is not available in app.config nor under any other name).

The code

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ClientContext, Configuration>());

var clientContext = new ClientContext(connectionString);

var y = clientContext.Set<TEntity>();
var z = await y.ToListAsync();
```

The Configuration class

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ClientContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

The ClientContext class

```
public class ClientContext : DbContext
{

    public ClientContext()
        : this(Properties.Settings.Default.OnlineConnectionString)
    {
    } 

    public ClientContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass true to the constructor (passing true to the constructor says that the migration should reuse client context triggering the migration). There is no need to manually supply the connection string to the initializer.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ClientContext, Configuration>(true));
```

Answer (score 2):

Set TargetDatabase in your db configuration class;

```
  public sealed class SomeConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SomeDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            //Creates a new instance of DbConnectionInfo based on a connection string.
            TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(
 connectionString:"The connection string to use for the connection",
 providerInvariantName:"The name of the provider to use for the connection. Use 'System.Data.SqlClient' for SQL Server.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to be able to supply the connection string directly as it is not present in app.config (it might be supplied by the user).